# Setting a type and an icon to files

Tags: windows-xp

Is it possible to set a different type (or description) and a different icon to several files that are associated with the same program?

For example: zip, rar, jar and xpi files open with WinRar, and they all have the type (WinRar Archive) and the same icon.

Changing one extension in ‘Folder Options’ affects all of them.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible using 3 methods: (using WinRAR as an example)

1. The easiest method is to use `Folder Options` to first delete the `WinRAR Archive` file type. Then create each each file types based on the archive file extensions. e.g.: `ZIP Archive` for `zip` extension, `RAR Archive` for `rar` extension, and so on. Assigning each with different icon and to be opened with *WinRAR*. Be aware that this method may break some complex programs like *Microsoft Office* or *Adobe Acrobat*. Specifically, those that involves *ActiveX*, whose document file can be opened from within *Internet Explorer* web browser.
2. The difficult method but has full editing control is to use *Registry Editor* to manually edit the file type associations. However, this is not recommended if you're not familiar with regitry editing including how file associations are stored in the registry as it's very risky and could easily break the system if mistake occurs.
3. The alternative method is to use third party program to edit them. I'm pretty sure there's one on the internet. Just be sure that it has an undo feature when you want to try one.

Comment: The first method didn't work. As soon as I open WinRar, all the changes are reset. I'm not very familiar with editing the Registry, but I'm going to try it.